# How to Replace Path in Search field using VIM

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I'm trying to replace this text in VIM

```
Actual Path /home/omipenguin/Servers\ Information/systemscript.sh/sysinfo.txt
```

with this new path

```
/home/sysinfo
```

I tried

```
%s/\/home\/omipenguin\/Servers\ Information\/systemscript.sh\/sysinfo.txt//home/sysinfo/g
```

but VIM gives me `Pattern not Found`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The forward slash `/` is used by `vim` as the default pattern separator: it separates the pattern from the substitution you want to make, so `vim` misconstrued the slashes in your path. You can specify another separator, like so:

```
%s!/home/omipenguin/Servers\\ Information/systemscript.sh/sysinfo.txt!/home/sysinfo!g
```

Note how you also need to escape the backslash `\` because of its special meaning in regular expressions.